# Why is Bootrstrap not putting the divs next to each other?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I the a MVC4 project with the following index.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="well">Hmm..</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8">left</div>
    <div class="span4">right</div>
</div>
```

The output seems to work halve because the div with the well gets a nice background color. But the navbar puts all the divs under each other instead of next to each other:

```
Title
  Home
  Link
  Link
```

This also applies for the row. That looks like this:

```
Left
Right
```

Does someone has a clue what's going on here?

Comment: Shouldn't you either be using the url helper with `~` or omitting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to apply `span` for the Divs.

```
<div class="span4">
  <p>Bruce Wayne</p>
 ...
</div>
```

It's some time since I used Bootstrap but I just took a quick look and it seems it's called col now or so. You can check it out further here, [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I guess I was looking at the wrong documentation. You are right about the usage of 'span'. Now you need to use 'col-md-<number>'